# ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore when integrating react-native-firebase in an existing react native project

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I've followed the guideline for integrating the Firebase SDK as a pod in a react native project (described in https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios), yet I keep bumping into this error:

ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore

My Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:

- AppCenter/Analytics (1.14.0):
  - AppCenter/Core
- AppCenter/Core (1.14.0)
- AppCenter/Crashes (1.14.0):
  - AppCenter/Core
- AppCenterReactNativeShared (1.13.0):
  - AppCenter/Core (= 1.14.0)
- Firebase/Core (5.20.2):
  - Firebase/CoreOnly
  - FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.8.1)
- Firebase/CoreOnly (5.20.2):
  - FirebaseCore (= 5.4.1)
- Firebase/Messaging (5.20.2):
  - Firebase/CoreOnly
  - FirebaseMessaging (= 3.5.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics (5.8.1):
  - FirebaseCore (~> 5.4)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.8)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 5.8.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 5.2)
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 5.2)"
  - nanopb (~> 0.3)
- FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.2.0)
- FirebaseCore (5.4.1):
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 5.2)
- FirebaseInstanceID (3.8.1):
  - FirebaseCore (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 5.2)
- FirebaseMessaging (3.5.0):
  - FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseCore (~> 5.2)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.6)
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.3)
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 5.3)
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 5.3)
  - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
- GoogleAppMeasurement (5.8.1):
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 5.2)
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 5.2)"
  - nanopb (~> 0.3)
- GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (5.8.0):
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network
- GoogleUtilities/Environment (5.8.0)
- GoogleUtilities/Logger (5.8.0):
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment
- GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (5.8.0):
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger
- GoogleUtilities/Network (5.8.0):
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
- "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (5.8.0)"
- GoogleUtilities/Reachability (5.8.0):
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger
- GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (5.8.0):
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger
- nanopb (0.3.901):
  - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.901)
  - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.901)
- nanopb/decode (0.3.901)
- nanopb/encode (0.3.901)
- Protobuf (3.8.0)

DEPENDENCIES:

- AppCenter/Analytics (~> 1.14.0)
- AppCenter/Crashes (~> 1.14.0)
- AppCenterReactNativeShared (~> 1.13.0)
- Firebase/Core (~> 5.20.1)
- Firebase/Messaging (~> 5.20.1)

SPEC REPOS:

https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:

- AppCenter
- AppCenterReactNativeShared
- Firebase
- FirebaseAnalytics
- FirebaseAnalyticsInterop
- FirebaseCore
- FirebaseInstanceID
- FirebaseMessaging
- GoogleAppMeasurement
- GoogleUtilities
- nanopb
- Protobuf
```

Podfiles:

```
target '<my_app_name>-devel' do
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.14.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.14.0'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.20.1'
  # Add new pods below this line

  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for <my_app_name>-devel

end

target '<my_app_name>-prod' do
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.14.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.14.0'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.20.1'
  # Add new pods below this line

  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for <my_app_name>-prod

end
```

React Native version: 0.59.5

React Native Firebase version: 5.20.1

Also tried with version: 5.4.3, 5.4.4

The documentation on this is pretty sparse, so any help or suggestions are welcomed

Comment: I'm assuming you've run `pod install` and opened the `xcworkspace` (not `xcodeproj`).   If you've done that, go to Xcode, select the app name, and then `Build Settings`.  Search for firebase - it should appear in `Framework Search Paths`

Comment: The only thing I found there was "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks". Instead, I found the search path for FirebaseCore (and the others) in the Library Search Path

Comment: That seems fine.  Also should see the firebase headers in the headersearchpaths but that shouldn't affect the library lookup.  Did you do the React Firebase installation (not just the pod) as described in the directions?

Comment: I did both of them.

Comment: hmn, I have a similar configuration and it's working for me.  sorry I can't help.